# Jquery - find next element in each loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, find, element

I have a question like so.

I have HTML structure:

```
<form id="form">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item-input">
            <label for="A1">A1</label>
            <input type="text" name ="A1" />
            <span class="input-require">(*)</span>
            <span class="info">(Enter A1)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-input">
            <label for="A2">A2</label>
            <input type="text" name ="A2" />
            <span class="input-require">(*)</span>
            <span class="info">(Enter A2)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="item-input">
            <label for="B1">B1</label>
            <input type="text" name ="B1" />
            <span class="input-require">(*)</span>
            <span class="info">(Enter B1)</span>
        </div>
        <div class="item-input">
            <label for="B2">B2</label>
            <input type="text" name ="B2" />
            <span class="input-require">(*)</span>
            <span class="info">(Enter B2)</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    ...
</form>
```

Now I want to selected 'span' has class "info" behind input[type=text] each. 
I try:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#form input[type=text]").each(function(){
            var spanInfo = $(this).closest("item-input").next().find('span.info');

            console.log(spanInfo.text()); // Result is empty
        });
    });
</script>
```

Why is empty? Help me please. How do I, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var spanInfo = $(this).closest("item-input").next().find('span.info');`

Should be

`var spanInfo = $(this).closest(".item-input").next().find('span.info');`

You are missing the . (dot, class)

Comment: I was'nt careful. :)
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your mean is show "(Enter A2)" and "(Enter B2)" or show all 4 element value: (Enter A1), (Enter A2), (Enter B1), (Enter B2)

If only show 2 value then [CODE HERE](http://jsbin.com/zejas/1/)

else You want to show 4 value, you can code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#form input[type=text]").each(function(){
        var spanInfo = $(this).closest(".item-input").find('span.info');

        console.log(spanInfo.text()); 
    });
});
```